# How to display all input fields one by one and only 4 input fields in one row using the below structure?

Tags: html, css

`

```
<div>
    <div><input /></div>
    <div>
        <div><input /></div>
        <div><input /></div> 
        <div><input /></div>
        <div><input /></div>
        <div><input /></div>
    </div>
    <div><input /></div>
    <div><input /></div>
    <div><input /></div>
</div>
```

`

I need to display all input fields one by one and only 4 input fields in one row using the below structure.

Comment: You should explain better what you want. This is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the flex display with a 25% width

```css
.input-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.input-container > div {
    flex: 1 0 25%; /* width of 25% */
    max-width: 25%; /* 25% width */
}

input {
    width: 100%; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
    <div><input /></div>
    <div><input /></div> 
    <div><input /></div>
    <div><input /></div>
    <div><input /></div>
    <div><input /></div>
    <div><input /></div>
    <div><input /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you mean one by one, but from what I did understand you could use a `display: flex` in the "inputs line".

So in your html you would have to add a class to the div that you want to become the line, like that:

```
<div>
    <div><input /></div>
    <div class="foo">
        <div><input /></div>
        <div><input /></div> 
        <div><input /></div>
        <div><input /></div>
        <div><input /></div>
    </div>
    <div><input /></div>
    <div><input /></div>
    <div><input /></div>
</div>
```

And then in your css:

```
.foo{
    display: flex;
}
```